# iOS Safari autofill sugestions overflap fixed position bottom element

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari

I have a very inconsistent issue with iOS Safari on iOS 10.2/10.2.1 (at least). On many iPhone 7,6,4 it works without an issue but on at least 2 iPhone 7 I had this issue.

I have a `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` input element on my page. If the placeholder is e.g. `Name`, Safari will offer to autofill it with a contact name in the suggestion box above the keyboard.
The problem is that on some devices, this suggestion box of the keyboard will overlap the input element at the bottom of the page:
[image]

The suggestion bar was expanded when the keyboard opened and was not manipulated afterwards by collapsing/expanding it.

On many tested devices this does not happen, only on a few of them.

Only the suggestion bar seems to be the issue. The normal input switch bar does not exhibit the problem. When I change the placeholder to something else, Safari won't try to autofill it and everything seems fine:
[image]
(Except for the small white gap at the bottom but I could live with that)

Does someone know why this might be happening on some devices? And maybe even how I could go about fixing this?

(Side note regarding a possible workaround: As I said it seems like Safari parses the placeholder to decide when and what to offer as autofill. When I change it to something else it won't show up. Simply disabling it for that one field like that would be finde but the same thing happens on an "Email" field and there is no smart alternative word to use as a placeholder.)

Comment: Same story here. With this innocent looking input field:
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
 <div><input type="text" maxlength="400" placeholder="Bitte hier schreiben"></div>
</div>
on an english iOS 10 the suggestion box above the software keyboard insists that I fill in my Contact. 
That's crazy. The placeholder simply states "Please type here" in German. Why would that be recognised as a contact form?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever it is worth, I just had this issue and resolved it by switching out the `<input>` element for a `<textarea>` element. Everything is working as expected -- I am not seeing the autofill suggestion anymore.